# Compare the first letter of a string in a struct

Tags: c, string, struct, strcmp

So i have the following problem i need to compare the first letter of two strings from a struct to see if one is bigger then the other. The objective of this is to implement in the bubblesort algorithm so that i can order the structure. So far i came by this line:

> if(strcmp(j->name,j->proximo->name)>0)

but this line compares the all the content in the strings i need only the first letter of both.

the full code is bellow

```
struct s_Especialidade{
    int id;
    char nome[60];
    char descricao[60];
    struct s_Especialidade *proximo;
};

void ordenarMedicoN(){
    PESPECIALIDADE i = malloc ( sizeof(Especialidade));
    PESPECIALIDADE j = malloc ( sizeof(Especialidade));
    PESPECIALIDADE t = malloc ( sizeof(Especialidade));
    for(i=cabecaEspecialidade; i->proximo != NULL; i=i->proximo) {
        for(j=cabecaEspecialidade; j->proximo != NULL; j=j->proximo) {
            if(strcmp(j->nome[0],j->proximo->nome[0])>0) {
                t = j;
                j = j->proximo;
                j->proximo = t;
            }
        }
    }
    main();
}
```

Comment: `if (j->name[0] > j->proximo->name[0])`.

Comment: Thx but that gives me an error code "main.c:408: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
main.c:408: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast" and i dont know why.

Comment: There is no `strcmp` in my condition. I compare plain `char`s with `>`.

Comment: good point i will try it out

Comment: @DanielFischer Common sense is not a frequent talent nowadays.

Comment: that `main();` is giving me the creeping horrors

Comment: Strictly speaking you have to compare the first characters interpreted as `unsigned char`, at least that is what strcmp() does.

Comment: why main is giving you horrors?

Comment: So i try it and no more errors but its seams my code simply do not work at all. he must be in circle and never stops any suggestion?

Comment: the implication of that main() is that the person writing it has misunderstood how the call stack works. it amounts to saying "once this function completes, keep everything that has been stored on the stack so far, and then start another instance of the program on top of this one, from the beginning"

Answer (score 1):

Your code is leaking memory.

It's never right to first do `malloc()`, then assign some other address to the same pointer, that loses the reference to the memory allocated by `malloc()`.

Also, consider just using [`qsort()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) from the standard library to do the sorting, it's perfectly capable of sorting any array once you've written the proper comparison function, and it's probably going to be faster than your algorithm.

Also, it's already written and debugged.

Answer (score 0):

Given your current code structure, you need to change the comparison to something like the following:

```
if( j->nome[0][0] > j->proximo->nome[0][0] )
```

This code snippet will compare the ASCII value of the first character (remember C starts counting from 0) of both strings.

However, keep in mind the following caveats:

- The comparison will be at the ASCII level, which means that upper-case and lower-case characters are not consecutive.
- You need to insert a check for `j->proximo` not being NULL, otherwise your code will segfault.
- As mentioned by others, the calls to malloc seem unnecessary. In other words, when you do `j = j->proximo`, you don't copy the content of the structure, you just update the pointer.